# La question sur le français en Belgique

Tags: discussion, scope

Est-ce que la question sur le français en Belgique est vraiment indésirable sur french.SE?

Cette question-ci: [French in Belgium](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25031/are-people-in-belgium-equally-likely-to-speak-dutch-as-they-are-to-speak-french).

Il s'agit bien d'une questions sur le français, même si ce n'est pas en France, et même si ce n'est pas pas une question sur une expression particulière. Je ne sais pas si ce site devrait se limiter à des explications sur des expressions, traductions ... seulement.

Si quelqu'un posait la question sur FSE de savoir combien il y a de patois en France, ou bien combien de gens parlent encore patois - ce qui me semble similaire à la question sur la situation du français en Belgiaue, est-ce que cela serait une bonne question pour FSE, ou une question digne seulement d'un guide touristique?

Answer (score 1):

La question [Are people in Belgium equally likely to speak Dutch as they are to speak French?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25031/are-people-in-belgium-equally-likely-to-speak-dutch-as-they-are-to-speak-french) ne porte pas sur la langue française, mais sur la géographie sociale de la Belgique. Ce site ne traite que des questions de langue, pas de culture ou de société. La question est donc hors sujet.

« Combien y a-t-il de patois en France » serait de même hors sujet. « Combien y a-t-il de patois français parlés en France » (excluant des patois d'autres langues que le français) rentre dans le sujet, puisqu'il s'agit de la langue française (mais par ailleurs ce n'est pas une question bien formée puisque la notion de patois distincts n'est pas bien définie).

Comment: Je trouve cela très discutable plutôt que factuel. Ce n'est qu'une façon particulière de comprendre "questions qui portent sur la langue française".

Comment: La question 24724 sur les langues "classy" du point de vue des Français ne porte pas du tout sur la langue française, en tout cas encore moins que la question sur le français en Belgique, elle est clairement une question de culture et de société, de plus sujette à opinions plus qu'autre chose, et pourtant elle survit.

Comment: Si la question posée avait été quelle est la chance de tomber sur un mandarinophone en choisissant une personne au hasard dans les rues de Hong-Kong, le hors-sujet ne ferait pas de doute. Dans notre cas, il est clair que la question aurait pu être posée sur travel.SE mais j'ai quand même trouvé sa fermeture un peu excessive. Les questions sur la francophonie, sur la pénétration de sa langue dans le monde ne sont pas expressément marquées comme hors-sujet dans la page d'aide de FSE et peuvent en raison du lien évident avec le français intéresser les linguistes, enseignants ou étudiants cités.

Comment: @Frank Si la [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/24724/358) c'est parce que seulement deux personnes en ont demandé la fermeture. Quant à la question sur le français en Belgique j'en ai demandé la fermeture parce que je pense qu'elle devrait être posée sur Travel SE.

Comment: L'étiquette "travel" me paraît déplacée car c'est une question sur la langue française qui peut intéresser les linguistes (il se trouve que je connais la personne qui a posé cette question, et qu'elle est linguiste, pas touriste). Laure: comment pouvez-vous demander la fermeture de cette question si la question 24724, qui ne porte **même PAS** sur la langue française, et qui est une question de culture, reste ouverte? 24724 devrait être sur Travel SE à la place de la question sur le français en Belgique, en toute logique.